# how to replace part of the URL with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have something like http://domain.com/Pages/SearchResults.aspx?function=search&selectedserver=intranet&search_query=MyRecords and need to replace it by JavaScript with something similar to http://domain.com/Pages/SearchResults.aspx?function=loginsearch&user=admin&password=admin&selectedserver=intranet&search_query=MyRecords — so

```
function=search
```

is being replaced with

```
function=loginsearch&user=admin&password=admin
```

inside the URL. Need help with what JavaScript should I save as a button on a browser's tool bar to click and have the URL in the address bar replaced.

Comment: that's an error, already fixed

Comment: Please tell me you are not sending a username and password in cleartext.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
var url = window.location.toString();
window.location = url.replace(/function=search/, 'function=loginsearch&user=admin&password=admin');
```

Comment: added a button with the following code:
javascript:var url = window.location.toString();window.location = url.replace(/function=search/, 'function=loginsearch&user=admin&password=admin');
and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Juan: depends on if it's in an `onclick` attribute or not.

Comment: There's no reason to run it as href="javascript: {...}"

Comment: Changing something in the URL is just possible by JS? Actually I'm trying to replace all spaces with `+` in the URL. How can I do that?

Comment: @MattBall What why? Why I what to replace spaces with `+` or why I want to do that by something else *(not JS)*?

Comment: Why do you want to replace spaces with `+`?

Answer (score 11):

The only way to update the displayed URL without reloading the page is [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

```
window.history.pushState('', '', '/your-new-url');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 location.href = location.href.replace(
    'function=search&', 'function=loginsearch&user=admin&password=admin&')
```

Answer (score 1):

My version. Works fine for me.

```
let url = window.location.toString();
window.history.pushState('', '', url.replace(searching_string, new_string));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find the dedicated library [URI.js](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js) helpful, particularly [setQuery()](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#search-set) and [addQuery()](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#search-add) methods. I pasted this chunk of code directly into the console on that page and it seems to work:

```
var url = 'http://domain.com/Pages/SearchResults.aspx?function=search&selectedserver=intranet&search_query=MyRecords';
var uri = new URI(url);
var new_params = {'function': 'loginsearch', 'user': 'admin', 'password': 'admin'};
uri.setSearch(new_params);
console.log(uri.toString());

http://domain.com/Pages/SearchResults.aspx?function=loginsearch&selectedserver=intranet&search_query=MyRecords&user=admin&password=admin
<- undefined
>
```

It should be easy to turn this logic into a function (or a one-liner :)). As an aside, why are you passing the credentials right in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

```
var url             = window.location.href;               
window.location     = url.replace(/function=search/, 'function=loginsearch&user=admin&password=admin');
```