# wordpress website for mobile. How to check the the device then redirect to mobile website URL

Tags: wordpress, web

i have created a wordpress website mobile version. now i've to deploy it on live server on the same url as for normal web version. my problem is how i check that the accessing device is mobile and move it to the mobile version of URL.  Suggest The code in header file or any other change in any file.

Comment: hi first to get Mobile_Detect.php using this url.
https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect
follow bellow define code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this check for mobile browser in header.php of wordpress theme and it works very fine and well for me.
Helping link for me
[Wordpress Mobile - Change Part of the URL Instead of Redirecting to the Front Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889115/wordpress-mobile-change-part-of-the-url-instead-of-redirecting-to-the-front-pa)

```
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
   if(preg_match('/android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4))){
header('Location: http://m.xyzabc.com');}
/* --- END DETECT MOBILE BROWSER ---*/
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
<?php wp_is_mobile(); ?>
```

This Conditional Tag checks if the user is visiting using a mobile device. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE or FALSE.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile

e.g.

```
<?php if(wp_is_mobile()){
wp_redirect('mobile_version');
}else{
wp_redirect('web_version');
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> get Mobile_Detect.php using this url.

https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

put file in your wordpress theme folder

> set code on your header.

```
require_once ("Mobile_Detect.php");

$conn   =   tep_db_connect();
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

$deviceType = ($detect->isMobile() ? ($detect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');

if ($deviceType=="phone") {
     wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 301 ); 
     exit;
}?>
```