# Javascript | Link/Bookmarklet to remove variables in url

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, urlvariables

I found this and was able to do what I initially wanted.
[Javascript | Link/Bookmarklet to replace current window location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802732/javascript-link-bookmarklet-to-replace-current-window-location)

```
javascript:(function(){var loc=location.href;loc=loc.replace('gp/product','dp'); location.replace(loc)})()
```

Which was to change an amazon url from the product link to the dude perfect link.

It turns this url: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01NBKTPTS/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NBKTPTS)

into this url: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01NBKTPTS/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NBKTPTS)

I would like to take this a step further. Is there a way to do the above switch and then also remove the string of variables after the ? essentially cleaning up

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01NBKTPTS/?pf_rd_r=DQV2YXJP8FFKM1Q50KS9&pf_rd_p=eb347dce-a775-4231-8920-ae66bdd987f4&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_t=Landing&pf_rd_i=16310101&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-2&linkCode=ilv&tag=onamzbybcreat-20&ascsubtag=At_Home_Cooking_210426210002&pd_rd_i=B01NBKTPTS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NBKTPTS)

to

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01NBKTPTS/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NBKTPTS)

Thanks!

Comment: https://dmitripavlutin.com/parse-url-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

You've almost done it yourself!

To do the second part you can use `split` on your `/?` string (i.e. URL).

In our case that will give you an array with two elements: the first element stores everything **BEFORE** the **`/?`** (reference **[0], that's what we can use**), and the other stores everything **AFTER** (reference [1], not needed for us)

> FYI: if there were more `/?`, then `split` would produce an array with several elements. [Additional information](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

In addition, you shouldn't forget to escape the special character `/` this way: `\/`.

So here is the final working bookmarklet code to get the first URL part before `/?` letters, with `gd/product` replaced by `dp`:

```
javascript:(function(){
    var loc=location.href;
    loc=loc
            .split('\/?')[0]
            .replace('gp/product','dp')
            +'/';
    location.replace(loc);
 })();
```